# What to do when completing a full-time masters by research, and a part-time job interferes with grades and progress?

Tags: masters

I'm currently in first year of MS by Research in computer science. The first year includes coursework and second year is research thesis.
I've been working part time 20 hours a week in a software company. I have 4 subjects. So far I have managed to complete assignments but haven't really studied well.
Now as the semester is close to end, I have projects, assignments and exams. I'm struggling to decide if I should continue working here. Sometimes I think it's doable but it's a little risky. I may not get proper marks to progress to next semester. What would you do in such situation?

Comment: The question really is not "Is it possible?" but "How much slower will progress be?"  Taking a full-time courseload while working is not the path most would take.

Comment: Well it's tough ! Really Tough ! I almost went crazy half way through. But I reminded myself, key is to never quit. However, I'm not getting time to study.

Answer (score 4):

It is most certainly possible to get a research degree while working part-time --- or even full-time.  I know a number of people who have done it.  As you are finding, it is quite rigorous, however.  In many cases, it may be better to take the *coursework* part time, so that you have enough space to really absorb the material, rather than just trying to hit passing marks.

Comment: Yeah, probably I should study part time and work part time. All 4 subjects I'm studying are really heavy but itneresting. I wish I had more time to go in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to focus on your studies full time, without working.  Do you have savings that would permit this?  Can you get a teaching assistantship?  What about a student loan?  Perhaps your employer would give you a leave of absence.